# Convert txt file to int array

Tags: python, arrays, io, int, python-2.x

I have a text file which looks something like:

```
-45 64 -41 -51
  95 96 -74     -74 56 41
41 64    -62 75
```

and I'm trying to convert it into an int array.

So far I tried making it one big String then convert it like that, but when I tried getting rid of the white spaces, the output still looks exactly like the txt file.

```
file = open("dir", "r")
line = file.read()
line.strip()
line.replace(" ","")
print line
line.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I just read it from the file straight into an int array?

Comment: What do you expect your output array to look like?

Comment: Could it be that you actually want to `split()` the strings?

Comment: Are you using numpy? If not, do you mean a `list` instead of an `array`?

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there - you need to use `str.split` instead of `str.strip` and `str.replace`. Then `map` the result to integers. You can also use a context manager that will close the file (not a `line`, by the way) automatically.

```
with open('dir') as f:
    content = file.read()
array = content.split()
numbers = map(int, array)
print array
```

Comment: in python 3, `map` produces a generator, not a list

Comment: @taylorswift And are we using Python 3 here? Note the `print` statement.

Comment: it is important to make sure people are aware of the difference, that in newer python, functions like `map` do not actually produce an “array” of items in memory

Comment: @taylorswift - But Python 3 has nothing to do with any part of this question. This is irrelevant.

Comment: since they are still talking about integer arrays, it sounds like the OP is very new to the language, in which case he/she may have selected version 2 arbitrarily without realizing there is a difference between the two. At any rate, it doesn’t hurt to know these things…and can save people a lot of confusion and frustration when the python interpreter they downloaded on their second computer doesn’t run the code right that worked fine on their other computer

Comment: @taylorswift - That is a separate issue that doesn't need to be discussed here. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension, an answer would be:

```
with open('dir', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

res = [int(i) for i in data.split()]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[-45, 64, -41, -51, 95, 96, -74, -74, 56, 41, 41, 64, -62, 75]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = []
fo = open("file.txt", "r")
    for line in fo:
        for nbr in line.split():
            myArray.append(int(nbr))
print myArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so this should work

import numpy as np

numbers = np.loadtxt('filename.txt', delimiter = '\t')